# How do I apply CSS to an EditorFor field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my view, I have the following `EditorFor<>` to display a numeric property. I want to control the width of the textbox created in the resulting markup.

When the view is rendered, the textbox is not 50px. It is 300px. The class specified in the CSHTML, `editor-field-score`, does not appear to be applied. I checked in Chrome with the developer tools and the class is not added to the resulting markup.

This is from my CSHTML:

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Animal, new { @class = "editor-field-score" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Animal)
</div>
```

This is from my CSS:

```
fieldset input[type="text"].editor-field-score { width : 50px; }
```

This markup is copied from Chrome:

```
<div class="editor-field">
   <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field XXX must be a number." id="Animal" name="Animal" type="text" value="">
   <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Animal" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do:

```
.editor-field input {
}
```

as your selector.

Otherwise, you can use TextBoxFor which does allow for the setting of HTML Properties like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Animal, new { @class = "editor-field-score" })
```